# I'm trying to add a method to a class using a wrapper that takes in some attributes

Tags: python, wrapper, python-2.x

I'm trying to add a wrapper that would add a method to a class that would return the value of the argument passed in to the wrapper, here is what I'd like to achieve:

```
@addMethod(test='abs')
class a(object):

    def method1(cls):
        pass

    def method2(cls):
        pass

def addMethod(*kwargs):
    def getTest():
        return kwargs.get('test')
    return getTest

def main():
    x = a()
    print x.getTest()
```

Expected output:

```
abc
```

I thought that my wrapper should inherit a new class that has the method, but that doesn't seem correct:

```
def addMethod(fn):

    def wrapped(self, *kwargs):
        return fn(AddDependency(kwargs))
    return wrapped


class AddDependency(object):

    def __init__(self, *kwargs):
        super(AddDependency, self).__init__()
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def getDependencyScript(self):
        return self.kwargs.get('test')
```

Any thoughts or hints that may lead me the right direction?

Comment: Note that a decorator with arguments is applied as follows: `thing = decorator(args)(thing)`. Also one `*` is for positional, not keyword, arguments and the first argument to an instance method should be `self`.

Comment: The cogent issues have been addressed already by Jon. You can find a working edit to your code here: https://repl.it/ISOk/0